# Stored Procedure or Calculated Columns

Tags: sql-server

This is a question of what is the best practice and best performance.

I have inherited a database that contains data for turbine engines.  I have found 20 data points that are calculated from several fields from the turbine.  The way it was done in the past is a view was create to pull data for some turbines and calculate some of the 20 data point.  Then other views for the same turbines but different data point and then other views for different turbines and data point.  So the same equations are used over and over.

I want to consolidate all of the equations (20 data point) into one place.  My debate is either creating a user function that will do all 20 calculations or creating them as computed columns in the table.  With a function it would calculate all 20 for each turbine even thou I might only need 2 or 3 for a view.  But as a computed column it would only calculate the columns the view pulled.

Comment: This question is so vague the only responses are purely opinion based. I would argue not using a function at all but that is my opinion.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit vague. But I would say computed columns sound ideal. Computed columns take up no space and just have the calculation run when they're called (so the 18/20 calculations NOT being used when a certain view is made, have no impact). There is however a little cost involve in doing those calculations every time. If you'd rather have them all pre-calculated at the cost of disk space, you can add the PERISISTED keyword to the computed columns.

Comment: I'll put in a vote for avoiding functions. When you do this, it causes SQL to process your results RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row), so computed column, or just a view with the calcs embedded in it are better options IMO.

Comment: Yea I left it vague so I could get others opinion.  Thanks for the imput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably "it depends".

The factors when making this determination include:

1. Is the column deterministic? (e.g. can you persist it or not)
2. How often is data inserted into the table?
3. How often is data retrieved from the table?

The trade offs for computed and specifically persisted computed columns are similar to that when considering an index on your table.  Having persisted columns will increase the amount of time an insert takes on the table, but allows retrieval to happen faster.  Whereas on the other end, computed columns (that aren't persisted), or a function you would have faster on the insert but slower on the retrieval.

The end solution would likely depend on the utilization of the table (how often writes and reads occur) - which is something that you would need to determine.

Personally, I wouldn't do a function for the columns, but rather I'd persist them, or write a view/computed columns that accomplished them, depending on the nature of the usage on the table.

Comment: Thanks.  I was leaning toward making them a calculated column.  But I wasn't going to make them persisted.  Records are not added to often the to table but the fields that are used in the calculations are changed on a regular bases.  So I do want to slow down updating the records.